# Broadcast Receiver on Network State change for TYPE_ETHERNET on Android

Tags: android

I am writing an application, which needs to check Ethernet(RJ45) connectivity.
for this purpose am using a broadcast receiver, but it is only working for Connected State, and my application hangs when I disconnect the Ethernet (RJ45).

here is my Broadcast receiver code and manifest.

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isConnected ;
        ConnectivityManager networkConnectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = networkConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();


        if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET)

            isConnected = true;

        else
            isConnected = false;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you should do a null-check for the active network info. It is stated on the API ref of the android that

> **[public NetworkInfo getActiveNetworkInfo ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29)**
>   Returns details about the currently active default data network. When connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections. You should always check isConnected() before initiating network traffic. This may return null when there is no default network.

Please have a look at the below code.

```
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null) {
            if (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET) { 
                  // is connected 
            }
        } 
    }
```